# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo Error using Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, swift5

I know this question has been asked before but none of the answers have fixed my issue. I'm getting the error:

> Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

I have another project where I'm using this exact method in another project that works perfectly fine. I have tried to place @objc in front of the functions but get this error:

> Objective-C method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` provided by method `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` conflicts with optional requirement method `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` in protocol `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {

        let editImage = editedImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

        guard let uploadData = editImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }

        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString

        let stoarageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(filename)
        stoarageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("Failed update profile image:", error)
            }

            stoarageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (downloadUrl, error) in
                guard let profileImageUrl = downloadUrl?.absoluteString else { return }

                print("Successfully updated image in storage:", profileImageUrl)

                let dictionaryValues = ["profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]

                Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).updateChildValues(dictionaryValues, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

                    if let error = error {
                        print("There was an error:", error)
                        return
                    }

                    print("Successfully saved user info to db")

                })
            })
        }
    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {

        let origImage = originalImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

        guard let uploadData = origImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }

        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString

        let stoarageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(filename)
        stoarageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("Failed update profile image:", error)
            }

            stoarageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (downloadUrl, error) in
                guard let profileImageUrl = downloadUrl?.absoluteString else { return }

                print("Successfully updated image in storage:", profileImageUrl)

                let dictionaryValues = ["profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]

                Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).updateChildValues(dictionaryValues, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

                    if let error = error {
                        print("There was an error:", error)
                        return
                    }

                    print("Successfully saved user info to db")

                })
            })
        }
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thank you for any help fixing this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Swift 5, Xcode 11**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            backgroundImage = (info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage)!
            ivBackground.image = backgroundImage

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not just Swift 5 problem. Type of `info` parameter for this delegate method was changed from `[String : Any]` to `[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]` a long time ago.

This is why compiler complains that your, in this case your **own**, method conflicts with method declared by implemented protocol.

So, you need to implement delegate's method with correct type of parameter

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    <#code#>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The new function name is what causes the error, it is confused with two **different** functions that do the same thing.

It used to be `[String : Any]` (which is what you have) but now they have changed it to `[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]`. This change just means that the info is going to be type of `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey`.

Try use this as your function name, it got changed a while ago (not in Swift 5):

```
@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
```

Hope this helps!